# How to store a string of float values delimited by comma into a float array?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a string of float values separated by a comma. I am trying to separate these values into individual array values. Although I am not getting any runtime errors, the program seems to be stuck in an endless loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char tempinput[13] = "100.00,200.00";

    float temp[2];
    int trial=0;
    char *aux;

    fgets(tempinput,13,stdin);
    aux=strtok(tempinput, ",");

    while(aux)
    {
        temp[trial] = atof(aux);
        trial++;
        aux = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }

    for(int i=0;i<trial;i++)
    {
        printf("%03.2f ",temp[i]);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Could someone please assist me with this code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Change it to `char tempinput[2000];` and `float temp[500]`. In general, either you need to provide *bigger than reasonably necessary* arrays, or you need code that prevents the user from overflowing the buffers. For toy programs, it's typical to just use big buffers. For production code, you need to protect against overflow.

Comment: BTW, you do realize that you need to type something, right? The string that you assigned to `tempinput` will not be used since `fgets` is going to overwrite it. And `fgets` is sitting there waiting for you to type something.

Comment: Always useful, try to place print out statements in order to see where your code actually halts (enters the loop).

Comment: Note: `tempinput[]` initially is not a _string_ as it lacks a _null character_.

Comment: regarding: `while(aux)`   This means if the input has 3 values, then the `temp[2]` buffer will be overflowed, resulting in undefined behavior and possibly a seg fault event.  Suggest:  `while( trial < 2 && aux)`

Comment: OT: regarding: `#include <math.h>`  nothing in the header file: `math.h` is being used by the posted code.  Including header files those contents are not used is a very poor programming practice.

Comment: OT: the function: `atof()` returns a value with type `double`.  So should cast the returned value to `float` to avoid an implicit conversion and to let the compiler know that you want the conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"fgets() reads a line from the specified stream and stores it into the string pointed to by str. It stops when either (n-1) characters are read, the newline character is read, or the end-of-file is reached, whichever comes first."*

It is important to note that fgets() **reads input from user, thus you need to provide input during runtime**. After testing your code, you can see that the program isn't actually stuck in endless loop but rather it waits for your input.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I realize now the `fgets()` line could be omitted altogether. Since I would need these float values in other codes, I would prefer declaring the values in the code itself.